# SQL Server query to find all current database names

Tags: sql-server

I need a SQL query to find the names of existing databases.

Comment: Hello Bob Jones! Please make sure you accept on answer as a correct/accepted one, in order to help future users.

Comment: @BobJones It looks like there's an answer down there that would work for you - could you accept one, to help future users?

Answer (score 74):

Here is a query for showing all databases in one Sql engine

```
Select * from Sys.Databases
```

Answer (score 52):

```
SELECT name  
FROM sys.databases
```

> You'll only see the databases you have permission to see.

Answer (score 10):

Another to add to the mix:

```
EXEC sp_databases
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't recommend this method... but if you want to go wacky and strange:

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB 'SELECT ''?'' AS DatabaseName'
```

or

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB 'Print ''?'''
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use these ways:

```
EXEC sp_helpdb
```

and:

```
SELECT name FROM sys.sysdatabases
```

**Recommended Read:**

Don't forget to have a look at [sysdatabases VS sys.sysdatabases](http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/blogs/AmitBansal/sql-server-bi/14/sql-server-sys-databases-vs-sys-sysdatabases)

A similar [thread](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/12/sql-server-2005-list-all-the-database/).

Answer (score 3):

[This forum](http://p2p.wrox.com/sql-server-2000/40098-select-all-database-names.html) suggests also:

> ```
> SELECT CATALOG_NAME AS DataBaseName
> FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
> ```

Comment: This didn't work on my machine.  MSDN says it is supposed to "contains one row for each database that has permissions for the current user." However the results were limited to only the current database.  "SELECT * FROM sysdatabases" works better for me.

Answer (score 0):

For people where "*sys.databases*" does not work, 
You can use this aswell;

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_SCHEMA from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Comment: this will table_schema e.g. `dbo` not name of DB

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false
```

#for postgres