# C# connect to database and list the databases

Tags: c#, sql, database, ado.net, sqlconnection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server query to find all current database names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873393/sql-server-query-to-find-all-current-database-names)

I am trying to figure out how to list the databases after connecting to the servers without specifying a database first.

```
sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Server=" + sqlServer + ";Database=" + database +    
";User ID=" + userName + ";Password=" + password + ";Trusted_Connection=False;");
```

So basically what i want is the end user to connect to the sql server, then have a drop down list populated with the list of db's they can connect and query.

Ideas?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use [`SqlConnection.GetSchema`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136366%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Yourserver; Integrated Security=True;"))
{
    con.Open();
    DataTable databases = con.GetSchema("Databases");
    foreach (DataRow database in databases.Rows)
    {
        String databaseName = database.Field<String>("database_name");
        short dbID = database.Field<short>("dbid");
        DateTime creationDate = database.Field<DateTime>("create_date");
    }
}
```

[SQL Server Schema Collections (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254969%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> To determine the list of supported schema collections, call the
>   GetSchema method with no arguments, or with the schema collection name
>   "MetaDataCollections". This will return a DataTable with a list of the
>   supported schema collections, the number of restrictions that they
>   each support, and the number of identifier parts that they use.

Comment: Of course `sqlConnection.Open();` should be wrapped in a `try{} catch(Exception e){}` in case of a bad login/timeout etc.

Comment: @Dannybecket: you should not use an empty catch to handle connection problems. Then its better to let the exception bubble to a global handler. Since it was not part of this question, i have not shown it.

Comment: An empty catch wasn't the idea, I was just pointing out that you should check for Exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

You can write a stored proc which can return you a list of databases on that server.

```
SELECT name
FROM master.sys.databases
```

or

```
EXEC sp_databases
```

Comment: Or connect directly to the master database and query it via code - assuming the SQL Login in the connection string has sufficient privileges to access master.

Answer (score 3):

This should get you database names:

```
var connectionString = string.Format("Data Source=localhost;User ID={0};Password={1};", userName, password);

DataTable databases = null;
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    sqlConnection.Open();
    databases = sqlConnection.GetSchema("Databases");
    sqlConnection.Close();
}

if (databases != null)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in databases.Rows)
    {
        foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} ", item);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Feel free to exclude all the printing at the end.  Toss all that in a console app to see it in action.  The table names are in index 0 of `row.ItemArray`.

Comment: Of course `sqlConnection.Open();` should be wrapped in a `try{} catch(Exception e){}` in case of a bad login/timeout etc.

Comment: You don't need to close the connection manually, since you wrapped it in a using statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SMO - [SQL Server Management Objects](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx&ei=1jt4UOPSLNHIsgbCwYGQCA&usg=AFQjCNGBjqAHr2-GMGelwJqBMWuFRgTzMw&sig2=R2vu_hazkXrYASxZ1ICPww).

This is two sample code in code project:

[SQL Server Authentication using SMO](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31826/SQL-Server-Authentication-using-SMO)

[Databases using SMO](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/123441/SQL-Server-2008-Backup-and-Restore-Databases-using)

Answer (score 1):

The most up to date list of databases will be in the database itself. Why not connect to `tempdb` as a default database (since you have to connect to something) to start with and then query from master.sys.databases.

`select [name] from master.sys.databases`

Then you can update your connection string with whatever database is necessary or simply change the db using the `ChangeDatabase()` method.

e.g. `connection.ChangeDatabase(selectedDB);`

You could also connect to master, but I like to keep default connections in tempdb as occasionally people forget to change databases before creating objects. I would rather the junk go into tempdb than master since tempdb is recreated when SQL restarts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
select * from master.sys.databases
```