# How can I access all databases in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm working on a query editor in which user enters a SQL query and in code behind I pass this query to a `SqlCommand` and execute it and display result to the user.

But there is one problem: how can I access all the databases in SQL Server which the user created? How can I set `initial catalog=` to access all databases in SQL Server, so that user enters any query,  then it will be execute against all those databases.

For example:

```
use db_compiler 
select * from std

use student 
select * from student
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'm going to say this - what you are requesting to do is a fundamentally BAD idea. SQL Injection is a concern among many, many other things.

However, if you want a list of the databases to set initial catalog, check out the answer to this question:
[SQL Server query to find all current database names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873393/sql-server-query-to-find-all-current-database-names)

Comment: But My question is how to set `initial catalog` access all the databases in sql so that it will execute any query from every db –

Answer (score 0):

you don't require to set `initial catalog` in order to be able to access to other databases.

Ability to access other database is determine by the permission of the login. If the login is able has the permission to access to other database, you can you use the 3 part naming convention to access it.

Example, even if the initial catalgo is DB1, it will be to access the TABLE3 in DB2

```
SELECT *
FROM   [DB2].[SCHEMA].[TABLE3]
```

For example instead of

```
use db_compiler 
select * from std
```

you can

```
select * 
from   db_compiler.dbo.std
```

Comment: Thanks for response then how can i use it?How can i use it in `connection string`??or where i use this statement?

Comment: it has nothing to do with connection string. You just need to speicfy the `[DB].[SCHEMA].[TABLE]` in your query to access other DB. But can't execute one query and expect the result to be return from All DB. You will need to execute the query one db at a time