# How to get all databases in pervasive from C# code?

Tags: c#, database, dto, pervasive

I want to list all databases on a server in a dropdownlist using pervasive and c#. Any advice or links for to read about it. Thanks

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/pervasive/ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873393/sql-server-query-to-find-all-current-database-names

Comment: I did not ask for code just for an advice or link for read and create my own. It's fun to see how people think ask for info for read is a kind of shortcut. But to ask for txt files shortcuts for answer the questions of the user that you don't even know it's  fine.

Comment: @Smartis - I put something in pastebin (which is where I had copied it from originally) https://pastebin.com/fe2z7XXc

Comment: @john - I put something in pastebin (which is where I had copied it from originally) https://pastebin.com/fe2z7XXc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look at the `DtoDatabase` class in the Pervasive DTO library [documentation](http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv12/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=dto/dto_data.5.03.html).

Comment: Thanks for the clue