# How do I retrieve a name of a database within a server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a databases within a server as follows and I want to ger a name of the database `S01_%`, where `%` is the latest date (the last part is a time).

[image]

bd_names() returns a name of current database...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server query to find all current database names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873393/sql-server-query-to-find-all-current-database-names)

Answer (score 1):

Use `sys.databases` to list all databases:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *, REPLACE(name, 'S01_', '') AS d
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name LIKE 'S01_%'
ORDER BY d DESC;
```

To get date part you will have to parse database name.

Answer (score 1):

You can query `sys.databases` with `order by name desc` and using `top 1` caluse.

```
SELECT top 1 name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name LIKE 'S01_%' 
order by name desc
;
```